# Add custom image to grid cell that is a RepositoryItemButtonEdit devexpress button

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I am trying to add a custom image to a grid cell that is a RepositoryItemButtonEdit devexpress button.

When I execute the following code, I see nothing on the button.

```
            Dim image As System.Drawing.Image =  System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\carl\addAccount.png")

            Dim buttonAdd As New RepositoryItemButtonEdit           
            buttonAdd.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.HideTextEditor
            buttonAdd.Buttons(0).Kind = ButtonPredefines.Ellipsis
            buttonAdd.Buttons(0).Image = image

            AddHandler buttonAdd.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click


            Dim unbColumn As GridColumn = gvView.Columns.AddField("Button")
            unbColumn.VisibleIndex = gvgvView.Columns.Count
            unbColumn.ColumnEdit = buttonAdd

            gvView.OptionsView.ShowButtonMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ShowButtonModeEnum.ShowAlways
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you see ellipsis instead of your image. It's because you set the EditorButton.Kind property to ButtonPredefines.Ellipsis. You need it to be Glyph. see the possible values at [ButtonPredefines Enumeration](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsButtonPredefinesEnumtopic).

```
    Dim image As System.Drawing.Image =  System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\carl\addAccount.png")

    Dim buttonAdd As New RepositoryItemButtonEdit           
    buttonAdd.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.HideTextEditor
    buttonAdd.Buttons(0).Kind = ButtonPredefines.Glyph
    buttonAdd.Buttons(0).Image = image

    AddHandler buttonAdd.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click


    Dim unbColumn As GridColumn = gvView.Columns.AddField("Button")
    unbColumn.VisibleIndex = gvgvView.Columns.Count
    unbColumn.ColumnEdit = buttonAdd

    gvView.OptionsView.ShowButtonMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ShowButtonModeEnum.ShowAlways
```